What does トゥケトゥケ mean?
In the song "Gigantic O.T.N." by "Giga", one of the lyrics is:

トゥケトゥケな　電波に乗った　感情論

I can't find a definition for トゥケトゥケ online or in any online dictionaries. Is it a na-adjective? Is it just an onomatopoeia? Is it an innuendo?

It's obviously being used as a na-adjective, but トゥケトゥケ does not have any specific meaning. It sounds somewhat like TikTok, but I'm not sure if there's any actual connection. It's perhaps similar in pupose to nonsense syllables such as "sha-la-la-la" or "doobee-doowop".
While I can easily recognize that the rest of the lyrics are full of sexual innuendos, I'm not aware of any connotations with the sound of トゥケトゥケ itself.
EDIT: Perhaps it's better to describe this as a made-up variant of チキチキ, "zing-zang" or "razzle-dazzle". It's not meant to have any specific meaning, but rather to add a playful, fun, rhythmic feeling.

どきどき come to mind...

It's definitely linked to ティック in gigantic... Also, pupose is a spelling error.
